Why isn't test change data correct?
Testing my Gen2 onDocumentUpdate function. But the change data in the function is not as expected. Can anyone see what's going on?
Here's a stripped down version of the code:

import { onDocumentUpdated } from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore';

export const onPrizeUpdate = onDocumentUpdated('prizes/{prize}', (event) => {
  const data = event.data.after.data();

  return data;
});

The test:
const functions = init(); // firstbase functions tests instance
const wrapped = functions.wrap(onPrizeUpdate); // wrapped function

describe('prize is pulled', () => {
  let change, beforeSnap, afterSnap;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    beforeSnap = functions.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(prize, `prizes/id`);
    afterSnap = functions.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(
      { ...prize, winner: user, winner_uid: user.uid },
      `prizes/id`
    );
    change = functions.makeChange(beforeSnap, afterSnap);
    await wrapped(change);
  });

  it('updates did_cakepull', async () => {
    // console.log('user', user);
    expect(user['show_1_did_cakepull']).toEqual(true);
  });
});

The aftersnap looks like this (in part). Looks good to me. The "change" object also looks good to me.
{
  _fieldsProto: {
    we_id: {
      integerValue: 12054,
    },
    show_id: {
      integerValue: 45,
    },
    cakepull: {
      booleanValue: true,
    },
 // ..... more props
}

But here is what's weird. In the actual function, the value of event.data.after.data() looks like this:
{
  aString: "foo",
  anObject: {
    a: "qux",
    b: "faz",
  },
  aNumber: 7,
}


Also when manually changing a document in the emulator UI the data in the function is as expected...
Here's the Firebase functions test wrapper (the #init function in the test) maybe this is not set up right?
import firebaseFunctionsTest from 'firebase-functions-test';

const init = () => {
  return firebaseFunctionsTest({
    projectId: 'dev',
  });
};

export { init };


Fixed by passing in the change like this:
await wrapped({ data: change });


See
data and params in onDocumentCreated Firebase function are undefined when called from firebase-functions-test
and
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues/205#issuecomment-1855885136
